# Question about analytic curves

Tags: gn.general-topology, differential-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Here a question that has me stumped.  Maybe someone familiar with algebraic or differential curves can help.  Suppose that $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an analytic function.  Is it true that the range of $\gamma$ is either homeomorphic to a line segment or contains a subset homeomorphic to $S^1$?

Comment: I believe so; let S={x | there exists y < x such that f(y)=f(x)}.  Then assuming S has a first element y, or is empty, gamma[0,y] is S^1, or gamma[0,1] is an interval.

If we assume gamma has an analytic continuation to some open neighborhood in C, then S is finite or gamma is a constant function, but I can't remember if real analytic is enough to guarantee that.  I think it is, but I won't add this as an answer since I'm not sure.

Comment: Wait, I meant gamma[x,y] in the above, where x is the point where f(x)=f(y).  But I can't edit comments.

Comment: @Richard: How does that argument apply to $\gamma(t)=\sin\pi t$? Then $S$ is not finite and doesn't have a first element (but the image of $\gamma$ is a line segment).

Comment: @George Good call, hm.  In my mind that was bookkeeping; in fact it was just wrong.  Was thinking about zero sets, and it doesn't quite generalize.

Comment: @George: post deleted. I read the question too quickly :)

Comment: Anyway, the answer must be yes. You just have to rule out cases such as where the curve doubles back on itself and then branches out to form a letter T. Considering the power series expansion at the branch point, it should be clear that this can't happen.

Answer (score 1):

@Richard: Real analytic is the same as complex analytic since locally the power series expansions converge on disks. Yes, $\gamma$ is analytic (or has analytic extension) to a neighborhood of $[0,1]$.